# Coloring a square grid by clicking

Tags: dynamic

I want to make an interface where a user can fill in a square grid by clicking. Some processing will then be done with these pixels to produce a new picture. How can I make this clickable interface? I thought about linking each little square to a set of mouse positions, but this seems unnecessarily complicated.

[image: Grid]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

just select n for a nxn grid

```
n = 5;
Grid[Partition[
Table[DynamicModule[{col = White}, 
EventHandler[
 Dynamic[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], col, Rectangle[]}, 
   ImageSize -> 
    Tiny]], {"MouseClicked" :> (col = 
     col /. {Black -> White, White -> Black})}]], {n^2}], n]]
```

here is the result

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get the information out of the picture e.g. {{0,0,0},{1,1,1},{0,1,0}} for a 3x3 grid?

Comment: @gilianzz I found a way to do this and posted an answer

Answer (score 5):

```
n = 10;
m = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
Row[{Dynamic[EventHandler[ArrayPlot[m, Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 300], 
  {"MouseClicked" :> With[{p = Reverse[{1, n} + {1, -1} Floor@MousePosition["Graphics"]]},
   m[[## & @@ p]] = m[[## & @@ p]] /. {0 -> 1, 1 -> 0}]}]], 
 Dynamic[Style[MatrixForm[m], 24]]}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should use Mesh -> True  in ArrayPlot

Comment: good idea, thanks @J42161217.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a "way to get the information out of the picture"

First Run the code in the first answer

Let's say you get

```
Out[15]=....(Grid)...
```

then you manipulate the grid and when you are done you must "run" (shift+enter) the final grid.

so, you'll get a new output like

```
 Out[17]=....(Grid)...
```

we are interested in the number "17" of the final output.
you take this number and place it in the begining of the function below

```
out = %17;
Map[ToExpression[(Characters @@ StringCases[ToString@InputForm[
      #], "vel[" ~~ __ ~~ "]}, E"])[[5]]] &, 
First[out], {2}] /. {0 -> 1, 1 -> 0}
```

this will give you the result you asked in the comment of the first answer